# Add two coordinates in a button function to launch mapKit and start navigation between two points (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

I'm using this class

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import MapKit

class FinalClass: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomInfoView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!



    var userLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places:[QPlace] = []
    var index:Int = -1

    var locationStart = CLLocation()
    var locationEnd = CLLocation()

    var mapView:GMSMapView!
    var marker:GMSMarker?






    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        guard index >= 0, places.count > 0 else {
            return


        }

        let place = places[index]
        let lat = place.location?.latitude ?? 1.310844
        let lng = place.location?.longitude ?? 103.866048

        // Google map view
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 12.5)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        self.containerView.addSubview(mapView)

        // Add gesture
        addSwipeGesture()

        didSelect(place: place)
        if userLocation != nil {
            addMarkerAtCurrentLocation(userLocation!)

        }
    }

    func addSwipeGesture() {
        let directions: [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection] = [.right, .left]
        for direction in directions {
            let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
            gesture.direction = direction
            self.bottomInfoView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
    }

    func addMarkerAtCurrentLocation(_ userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D)  {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = userLocation
        marker.title = "Your location"
        marker.map = mapView
    }

    func didSelect(place:QPlace) {

        guard let coordinates = place.location else {
            return
        }

        // clear current marker
        marker?.map = nil

        // add marker
        marker = GMSMarker()
        marker?.position = coordinates
        marker?.title = place.name
        marker?.map = mapView
        mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        moveToMarker(marker!)

        // update bottom info panel view
        let desc = place.getDescription()
        descriptionLabel.text = desc.characters.count > 0 ? desc : "-"
        distanceLabel.text = "-"

        // update distance
        if userLocation != nil {
            let dist = distance(from: userLocation!, to: coordinates)
            distanceLabel.text = String.init(format: "Distance %.2f meters", dist)
            self.drawPath(startLocation: userLocation!, endLocation: coordinates)
        }

        title = place.name
    }

    func moveToMarker(_ marker: GMSMarker) {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: marker.position.latitude,
                                              longitude: marker.position.longitude,
                                              zoom: 12.5)
        self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
    }

    // distance between two coordinates
    func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)

       return from.distance(from: to)

    }

    func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        guard index >= 0, places.count > 0 else {
            return
        }

        if sender.direction == .left {
            if index < places.count - 2 {
                index += 1
                didSelect(place: places[index])
            }
        } else if sender.direction == .right {
            if index > 1 {
                index -= 1
                didSelect(place: places[index])
            }
        }
    }




    func drawPath(startLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D, endLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        let from = CLLocation(latitude: startLocation.latitude, longitude: startLocation.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: endLocation.latitude, longitude: endLocation.longitude)

        let origin = "\(from.coordinate.latitude),\(from.coordinate.longitude)"
        let destination = "\(to.coordinate.latitude),\(to.coordinate.longitude)"


        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data as Any)     // server data
            print(response.result as Any)   // result of response serialization

            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
            let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

            // print route using Polyline
            for route in routes
            {
                let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
                let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                polyline.strokeWidth = 4
                polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.black
                polyline.map = self.mapView
            }

        }

    }


    @IBAction func navigationStart(_ sender: Any) {





    }
```

with a google maps to add place markers, draw the direction on the map and show the distance between two points, now i would like to launch the navigator between `startLocation: userLocation!` and `endLocation: coordinates` but with some research i saw that i can not launch the navigator in the same view, i need to open the maps application, so i decided to add the MapKit and a button

```
@IBAction func navigationStart(_ sender: Any) {


}
```

so how can i do that by pressing the button the map application opens with direction from `userLocation` to `coordinates` ? I already looked to similar question but is a little different to my problem, because i already have the points but in different format.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing but if you want to open the maps app and show direction from a user's current location to another point on the map then you don't need to pass the user's location, just the destination:

Swift 4:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5007, -0.1246)
let placeMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placeMark)
mapItem.name = "Big Ben"
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
```

Objective C:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5007, -0.1246);
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate: coordinate];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:@"Big Ben"];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];
```

Comment: yes my only problem is that, if you look at my code, my destination is represented by this   func didSelect(place:QPlace) {

        guard let coordinates = place.location else {
            return
        }  so the constant  "coordinates" is the destination, i don't know how to add this constant in the func of the button

Comment: Why not store a reference to it then? Or obtain the place when the button is pressed?

Comment: i obtain the place in a previous vc, how can i store a reference to it?

Comment: It's not ideal but I just mean store a reference in your ViewController.